# Redux reducer key issue

Tags: react-native, redux

I am trying to learn Redux in React, and I have a reducer:

**reducers/index.js:**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

export default combineReducers({
    foo: () => []
});
```

And I am creating my store using:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { reducers } from './reducers'; // ./reducers/index.js is implied
import { Header } from './components/common'; 

const app = () => (
    <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
        <View>
            <Header headerText="Foo App" />
        </View>
    </Provider>
);
```

But for this I get an error:

> Console.error: "No reducer provided for key foo"

I am simply trying to return an empty array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just try like you did here and look like he work. https://codesandbox.io/s/w7jw0nzwl7 Can you show how you create your store ?

Comment: Seems like I am doing the same ... still not sure what the issue is. Added some more information above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is the way you import your reducer. You export it as default so you need to remove the curly bracket around it.

`import reducers from './reducers';`

If you have done `export const reducers //....` now you would have need to `import { reducers } from './reducers';`

Comment: Ah, I missed that! Thanks :)